# Program does not enter if statement

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, if-statement

So I have a mistake detection program that should detect a "mistake" if the current word (String cWrd) is not contained in a static array (passed as a parameter). If the word is not found in the array, "boolean found" remains false and a JLabel is set to "wrong category" for some period of time. **However, the method does not appear to execute even when cWrd is not contained within the array.**

CODE:

```
//Mistake method
public void mistake(String[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (i < arr.length && found == false) {
        if (arr[i].equals(cWrd)) {
            found = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (found == false) //The program never enters this if statement
    {
        lmid.setText("Wrong Category!");
        try {
            t1.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here are the two arrays I am testing with

```
String[] positive =
{"Happy","Beautiful","Wonderful","Generous","Loving","Supportive","Caring"};
String[] negative =  {"Nasty","Gross","Horrible","Obnoxious","Mean","Disaster","Angry"};
```

Here is the method that sets cWrd = to a random word from a combination of both positive and negative arrays (ArrayList  not pictured)

```
public void wordGen()
   {
      wchooser = rand.nextInt(words.length);
      lmid.setText("            " + words[wchooser]);
      cWrd = lmid.getText();
   }
```

Comment: change `if (found = false)` to `if (found == false)`

Comment: What is arr.length when execution hits the while loop?

Comment: thank you, I changed the title. I altered the = to == but the GUI still appears to not be phased by the method. @gla3dr

Comment: Just use `if (found)` or `while (!found)`. `if (found == true)`...`while (found == false)`, it's redundant.

Comment: better yet change it to `if(!found)`

Comment: BTW: `t1.sleep(100);` will not sleep on `t1` Thread, but on current thread. This is one of standard examples of why we should avoid invoking static methods from references rather than classes. To put it simply `t1.sleep(100);` is same as `Thread.sleep(100);`.

Comment: I actually am starting to believe that the thread is the problem after fixing the = to ==. @Phesmo How would I put the current thread to sleep after mistake is displayed for an x amount of time?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *current thread* since `Thread.sleep` will affect thread which will execute this code (in the meaning current thread). If you want to pause *other thread* then you should probably use some kind of volatile *signal* which will be checked in that thread.

Comment: When debugging code, use of Random without a forced seed is generally a mistake. It makes it impossible to reproduce runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although tests like `found == false` (**not** `found = false`) are valid, the code will be more readable and less error-prone if you change it to the equivalent `!found`.

I modified your program to do output rather than sleep to make the results more visible, the sort of thing one should do when narrowing down a bug, and it appears to me to be working. Regardless of whether the string is found or not, it reaches the if-statement and takes the correct path through it.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.mistake(new String[] { "aaa", "bbb" });
    t.mistake(new String[] { "xyzzy", "aaa", "bbb" });
  }

  String cWrd = "xyzzy";

  public void mistake(String[] arr) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    while (i < arr.length && !found) {
      if (arr[i].equals(cWrd)) {
        found = true;
      }
      i++;
    }
    if (!found) // The program never enters this if statement
    {
      System.out.println("Wrong Category!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Found!");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Wrong Category!
Found!
```

Comment: I changed it to if(!found), same results.

Comment: @imgolden62 What results? What did you expect, and what happened?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment operator rather than a comparison operator.

This:

```
if (found = false)
```

Should be:

```
if (found == false)
```

Otherwise `if (found = false)` will always evaluate to `false` and will never enter the loop.

If changing the operator doesn't work, then we can only assume that the value of `cWrd` is being found and setting the `found` variable to true, which is why the statement isn't executing.

Personally, I'd set my debugger up and step through the code and figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: why does he have to make it "cwrd"? he could have a global variable. It wouldn't compile for him if he didn't

Comment: @BrandonLing considering that it's never defined or declared, I'm assuming that he is looking for the string literal.

Comment: cwrd is a global variable. I don not understand why it needs to be cWrd.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai but like i said, his code wouldn't compile, and he wouldn't complain about his if-statement not being reached

Comment: @imgolden62 if it's a global variable, I'd include all relevant code, like what the value of the array your searching is and what the value of cWrd is.

Comment: Ok i will do that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Change = to == in your condition.

Comment: Ok i have done that, but it still does not execute as intended

Comment: `=` vs `==` looks like typographical error, which are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you believe that this is only problem then you should vote to close this question rather than posting answer. You can help OP by posting comment about this problem, but don't prevent such questions from being automatically deleted by having upvoted answer there. (this comment applies to all answers here)

Answer (score -1):

correct this:

```
    if (found == false)     //The program never enters this if statement
    {
    lmid.setText("Wrong Category!");
    try {
        t1.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: I am not saying that your answer is wrong, but can you explain how is it different than others already posted? Generally if you agree with other answers and your answer doesn't add anything new instead of posting it you should upvote already existing answers which you agree with.